# Error in Calling Matlab Function from C# script

Tags: c#, matlab

I want to call matlab function from c# script.

I followed all the steps mentioned on matlab's official website for said purpose but at line `MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();`

I get an error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast COM object of type
>   'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'MLApp.MLApp'.

Thanks

Comment: What are the instructions that you followed? Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: instruction given in following link: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-function-from-c-client.html------------------ 1. made a simple matlab function. 2. copied c# script from above link and pasted it in c# console application. 3. when i started executing c# script i get an error at ' MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp(); .

Comment: i also added matlab reference in c# script.

Comment: Please add this information [in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62076616/edit).

Comment: sir added the information.